# Отсортировать данные по значению целыми блоками

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый День!
Есть база вида

```
============================
x
y lvl
============================

============================
x1
y1 lvl
============================

============================
x2
y2 lvl
============================
```

Помогите отсортировать данные по возрастанию значения *lvl*. Сортировать поблочно, не меняя расположения данных внутри блоков.

Желаемый результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откорректировал Ваш вопрос,  свои комментарии (теперь уже лишние) удалил. Удалите и Вы свои. Постараюсь помочь макросом.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Огромное!

Comment: Ой... Жесть какая-то...

Comment: Возникает вопрос, зачем хранить данные в таком виде. Если бы данные были разбиты по столбцам, работать с ними было бы намного проще.

Comment: Откуда данные попадают в excel?

Comment: Полностью согласен - структура данных "никакая".  Но сортировать можно.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить первую пустую строку (для *шапки*). В *C2* вписать формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2="";C1;ЕСЛИ(ПРАВБ(B4;3)="lvl";--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(B4;"lvl";);C1))
```

Протянуть формулу до последней заполненной строки.

Установить автофильтр: выделить *шапку* полученной таблицы, вкладка *Данные-Фильтр*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сортировать по дополнительному столбцу. После этого можно удалить доп. столбец и первую строку.

Практически то же самое, но переведенное в код *VBA*. Формулы в доп. столбец вставляются и удаляются из него без ручного вмешательства. Автофильтр на листе не установлен.

```
Sub SortLvl()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lRw As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' отключаем обновление экрана'
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    With sht
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' размер диапазона столбца B'
        .Range("C2").FormulaLocal = "=ЕСЛИ(B2="""";C1;ЕСЛИ(ПРАВБ(B4;3)=""lvl"";--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(B4;""lvl"";);C1))"
        .Range("C2:C" & lRw).FillDown ' формула на весь диапазон'
        .Range("B1:C" & lRw).AutoFilter ' ставим фильтр'

        ' сортировка'
        With sht.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=sht.Range("C2:C" & lRw), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange sht.Range("B1:C" & lRw)
            .Apply
        End With

        .Range("C2:C" & lRw).ClearContents ' очищаем вспомогательный диапазон'
        .Range("B1:C" & lRw).AutoFilter ' снимаем фильтр'
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' включаем обновление экрана'
End Sub
```

*Alt+F11* - вход в редактор *VBA*. Слева - дерево проекта. Код разместить в общем модуле проекта (если его нет, добавить - *Insert-Module*). Как запускать макрос - в сети полно информации

**Доп. совет:** меняйте расположение данных. У Вас не таблица, а набор текстов, который сложно обрабатывать средствам *Excel*. Все равно что на листике тетрадном написано )

Два столбца: имя, значение. Не нужно разделять блоки, один "блок" - это одна строка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такое *Excel* любит и не попросит никаких дополнительных извращений для сортировки.

Comment: Спасибо! Но руками я и так могу отсортировать. Хотелось более легкий вариант. И при совпадении данных такая сортировка разрушит блок.

Comment: Перед тем,как писать, нужно проверить. При совпадении данных ничего не нарушится. Это первое. Второе: такая структура данных , кроме затруднения работы с ней, приносит какую-то пользу? Почему именно так? Почему не сделать нормальную таблицу? Имеет ли смысл писать под такое макрос? Применение VBA будет проще только если работа с такими данными не разовая.

Comment: День добрый! Если честно то я думал, что существует готовое решение, и ни как не хотел кого-то напрягать. Работа не разовая я сортирую для себя в ручную.

Comment: Добавил макрос. Вставить код в общий модуль, назначить его выполнение какой-нибудь кнопке... Подставлять данные в столбец В, нажимать кнопку и копировать отсортированные данные